# How can I add a backslash using sed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I want to add a backslash `\` printed between `Hello` and `World` in command line using `sed`. It should show output `Hello \ World`.

What do I have to do?

Comment: that backslash is not  very useful. If it's intended to escape the space when the string is used again for something, it needs to come before the space, like `hello\ world`

Comment: Related: [Search and replace a pattern containing backslashes](//askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1644308)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a file named `hw` containing `Hello World`, the sed command would be:

```
sed 's/ / \\ /' hw
```

This displays the wanted result on the screen. If you want to edit the file, add `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/ / \\ /' hw
```

The command replaces the space by space\space. You need two `\\` because `\` is an escape character.

Comment: Perl people call this [_leaning toothpick syndrome_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I used a text file containing the texts `Hello World` and with this sed command:

```
sed 's/Hello/Hello \\/' helloworld.txt
```

And the output is:

```
Hello \ World
```

Note: This can be used too:

```
sed 's/World/\\ World/' helloworld.txt
```

The sed command finds the `Hello` text and adds a `\` to the front and that outputs the result seen. The `\\` escapes the `\` so it's seen as a real (literal) `\` not a special character.

Answer (score -3):

I used `\` at the end of code like this:

```
sed -i -r "Hello \\ World \\" mytext.txt
```

This resulted in `Hello \ World`, as desired. But thank you, all.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong typing for my answer and I have edited it..

Comment: Thanks, that does make a little more sense, but it's still missing an actual `sed` command I think? Can you check again what exactly you wrote?

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an explanation of what you tried (incorrectly) before you read the other answers?

Comment: @Garry14 The command you typed here was ``sed -i -r "Hello \\ World \\" mytext.txt``, but each ``\\`` was displayed as ``\``. That's fixed now, and we've undeleted this, but it still doesn't fully make sense. You need a command, like `c`, to make this work. That is, ``sed -i -r "cHello \\ World \\" mytext.txt`` (better written ``sed -i -r 'cHello \ World \' mytext.txt``) *does* work. Is it possible you ran such a command? Can you **[edit]** to clarify? Once `c` or something like it is added, the backslash at the end *does* actually make the one in the middle appear, which is quite interesting.

Comment: One possibility is that rather than the `-i` flag, or additionally to the `-i` flag, you used `sed`'s `i` (insert) command. That would produce the output you showed, provided there was already something in the file. Note that since the shell will not do anything to `i` by itself, it needn't be quoted. This works: `sed i"Hello \\ World \\"` and this also works `sed "iHello \\ World \\"` (whether or not the `-i` and `-r` flags are included)